# Run commands in series and stop when first command exits with 0

Tags: bash, shell-script, mongodb

I have these 3 commands:

```
  mongo cdt_prod_playground --host "mngdb-cbt-stg-01:27058" -u cdtprodplayground -p "x" --eval "db.${file%.*}.remove({})"
  mongo cdt_prod_playground --host "mngdb-cbt-stg-02:27058" -u cdtprodplayground -p "x" --eval "db.${file%.*}.remove({})" 
  mongo cdt_prod_playground --host "mngdb-cbt-stg-03:27058" -u cdtprodplayground -p "x" --eval "db.${file%.*}.remove({})"
```

I want to run them and stop when the first one succeeds. One way to do that I guess would be to them into an array and break out of the loop when the commands succeeds, but how do I do that?

(The reason is I need to do this is because I don't know which host is the replica set PRIMARY, so I just have to test it brute force, because I don't have the authorization to run `rs.status()`.)

Answer (score 3):

Instead of trying a command on all replica set members to figure out which one is the current primary, you should use a replica set connection string with your `mongo` command line. You can optionally include username and password credentials in the connection string instead of using separate command line parameters.

Example using the MongoDB 3.6.3 shell:

```
mongo "mongodb://USERNAME:PASSWORD@mngdb-cbt-stg-01:27058,mngdb-cbt-stg-02:27058/DATABASE?replicaSet=cdt_prod_playground" --eval "db.${file%.*}.remove({})"
```

You don't have to list all members of your replica set in the connection string. I used two in my example above as that should ensure discovering the primary in a three member replica set (which needs 2/3 voting members available to maintain a primary). The driver/client will determine the current members as long as you include the `replicaSet` name in the connection string and at least one of the members in the connection string is healthy.

See [Connection String URI Format](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/connection-string/#standard-connection-string-format) for a reference of available options.

Also note that calling `db.collection.remove({})` will delete individual documents while maintaining the index definitions. If you have a significant amount of collection data to remove, it would be faster to call `db.colellection.drop()` and recreate any required indexes.

> The reason is I need to do this is because I don't know which host is the replica set PRIMARY, so I just have to test it brute force, because I don't have the authorization to run rs.status()

If you need to discover the current primary programatically, you can use the [`isMaster` command](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/isMaster/). This command is used by MongoDB drivers and clients (like the `mongo` shell)  as part of the initial connection negotiation. When connected to a replica set member, the `isMaster` output includes `primary` and other details for current [replica set state](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/isMaster/#replica-sets).

As at MongoDB 3.6 the `isMaster` command does not require authentication, since it is used to provide information that drivers/clients need for server discovery and negotiating an authenticated connection.

Answer (score 2):

IIUC, you could join the lines with `||` if `mongo` returns non-zero on error.  As described in `man bash`:

```
An OR list has the form

           command1 || command2

   command2 is executed if and only if command1 returns a non-zero exit status.  The return status of AND and OR lists is the exit status of the last command executed in the list.
```

I don't have `mongo` here but I can post an example `succeeds.sh`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env sh
nonexistent-command || \
echo a || \
echo b || \
echo c
```

Run:

```
$ ./succeeds.sh
./succedds.sh: line 3: nonexistent-command: command not found
a
```

As you can see the script stops at `a` because it's the first command that has succeeded.

Answer (score 1):

```
hostlist=(mngdb-cbt-stg-01:27058 mngdb-cbt-stg-02:27058 mngdb-cbt-stg-03:27058)
hostnum=0
set -u
/bin/false; while [[ 0 -ne $? ]]; do 
  mongo cdt_prod_playground --host "${hostlist[$hostnum]}" -u cdtprodplayground -p "x" --eval "db.${file%.*}.remove({})"
  hostnum=$((hostnum+1))
done
```

Comment: IMHO `hostnum` is redundant in this case. I'd substitute that `while` part with `for host in "${hostlist[@]}"; do command "$host" && break; done`

Comment: A cat with many skins.